# How to use RtAudio with Direct Sound on windows

Tags: audio, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

The RtAudio documentation says.

Windows (DirectSound):

The configure script provides support for the MinGW compiler. DirectSound support is specified with the "--with-ds" flag.

In order to compile RtAudio under Windows for the DirectSound API, you must have the header and source files for DirectSound version 5.0 or higher. As far as I know, there is no DirectSoundCapture support for Windows NT. Audio output latency with DirectSound can be reasonably good, especially since RtAudio version 3.0.2. Input audio latency still tends to be bad but better since version 3.0.2. RtAudio was originally developed with Visual C++ version 6.0 but has been tested with .NET.

The DirectSound version of RtAudio can be compiled with or without the UNICODE preprocessor definition.

It says I must have a header and source files for DirectSound. So do I need to write these headers and source files in C++ or I can get hold of them from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the DirectSound headers and libs as part of the DirectX SDK from Microsoft. I went to the [Microsoft Download Center](http://download.microsoft.com), searched for "DirectX SDK", sorted by release date, then downloaded the most recent one. Here's a direct link to it: [DirectX SDK - (June 2010)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/7/AE743F1F-632B-4809-87A9-AA1BB3458E31/DXSDK_Jun10.exe).